# If statement return loop

Tags: java

Just a declaimer:i am a beginner in java.

Write a method named numUnique that takes three integers as parameters and that returns the number of unique integers among the three. For example, the call numUnique(18, 3, 4) should return 3 because the parameters have 3 different values. By contrast, the call numUnique(6, 7, 6) would return 2 because there are only 2 unique numbers among the three parameters: 6 and 7.

```
public int numUnique(int x,int y,int z){
    if(x==y||y==z){
    }
    return 1;

    else if(x!=y||y!=z){

    }
    return 2;
    
}
```

I am very confused about the relationship of if and return.I always put return inside if statement.But i dont understand why does it generate me an error message.if something is fulfil,i return in the loop.Why is it wrong.But on the other hand,the println statement can be put inside for loops.

Another issue,because this question,i tried to attempt using if else too.But my first condition is if and i return it.So after that i placed else if after the first return,it gives me error again.

I will appreciate someone will explain to me and i will alter the codes on my own.Please dont give me the full codes.Thank you.

Edited*
By the way,i read through all the comments and i finally understand it.This is my codes that i work out on my own(:

```
public static int numUnique(int x, int y, int z) {
    if(x==y && y==z){
        return 1;
    }else if(x==y && y!=z || y==z && z!=x ||  x==z && y!=z ){
        return 2;
    }
    return 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your return are outside the `if` statements, they should be inside. Because if you write:

```
if(Something) {

}
return 1;
```

Then 1 will be always returned because your `if` is empty. If you want to `return 1` only `if(Something)` then write it inside the `if` body:

```
if(Something) {
    return 1;
}
```

Second, your logic is not good. You need to check:

- if x == y == z then they're all equal.
- if x == y and x != z then you should return 2.
- if x != y != z then you should return 0.
- ....

You need to cover all situations.

Comment: I agree my logic is not good.So i spent hours trying to brush up on my logic.Repeated this mod for the second time and my logic is still so weak.

Comment: That's why I told you what you need to do. It's very easy, just think when the numbers are all equal, when only two are equal. Write it down and you'll see it's not difficult.

Answer (score 2):

The return statements should be placed within the curly bracets.

Comment: This still doesn't solve his problem. His logic is not good. (and I didn't downvote :) )

Comment: It is ok.I dont understand why is there so many downvotes.been practising for hours and got stuck so came here to seek here after reading up on my own.

Comment: @user2179615 Better grammar and punctuation would help, honestly.

Comment: Alright.I shall go and edit.English is not my main language so i am rather weak.Sorry for that.

Comment: @user2179615 please note that as this seems like an homework assignment, what I suggest will not solve the problem completely but I believe it will help you understand what is going on.

Comment: I need to clarify myself.I hate being accused.Because i am weak in java,i spent hours doing practices on practiceit.This is not a homework assignment.Just doing random practcies to brush up my skills as i am weak.

Comment: @user2179615 I am not acusing you of anything. Even if that is not a homework assignment it is better if you come up with the solution on your own. So I am just giving you a hint guiding you in the correct direction.

Comment: Yes.i take in all the comments below and understand it and i work it through slowly.What do i even want the solutions?It will be no help to me during exam.So i hope you dont assume.It is very hurting for someone who practises like 7hours continuously and people simply assume.I appreciate your help anyway.The best way to learn is understand it and work through on your own.That is what i am doing.

Answer (score 2):

To give you a clear understanding of "return" statements, i will say there can be only one return statement in one block of code i.e {...}.

"return" statement is used to return to the caller, and it has to be last statement of the block.

As suggested by you i am not providing you complete code, rather making you aware of usage of "return" statement.

In your code you are writing two "return" statements in one block.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for a what you want looks like this:

```
   public static  int numUnique(int x,int y,int z){
        if(x==y||y==z){
            return 1;
        }else if(x!=y||y!=z){
            return 2;
        }
        return 3;
    }
```

Maybee this code ist better understandable:

```
public static int numUnique(int x, int y, int z) {
    if (x == y && x == z && y == z) {
        return 3;
    } else if (x != y && x != z && y != z) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 2;
}
```

Pseudocode If

```
if( condition ){
 // do something if condition is true
}
```

Pseudocode If then else

```
if( condition){
 // do something
}else{
 // do something if condition is false
}
```

Pseudocode elseif

```
if( condition ){
// do something
}else if(condition2){
// do something, only if condition2 is true, if condition 1 is true, you never will be here
}else{
// do something, your only here if the two conditions above were false
}
```

A return statement, immidiently brakes execution ( there are some exception, exmaple: the finally block)

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to write return statements inside if-else blocks otherwise it will always return 1

Comment: But i placed it outside and it works until i wrote those if else statement

Answer (score 0):

since if is a conditional flow, i may or may not run (depending on the condition),

but if your method has return type it should return in every cases. But in the later case, (if condition is false), it wont find any return.

so if you write

```
public int value(boolean flag){
if(flag){
return 0; //only reachable if flag is true, else value can not return from here
}
}
```

it is wrong, since if flag is false method wont return anything. so you must provide a return in `else` or after `if` block ends

Answer (score 0):

using the fact that `Set`s store values only once...

```
public int numUnique(int x,int y,int z){
    Set<Integer> number = new HashSet<Integer>();
    number.add(x);
    number.add(y);
    number.add(z);

    return numbers.size();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the return statement in the block from if and else:

```
public int numUnique(int x,int y,int z){
  if(x==y||y==z){
    return 1;
  }
  else if(x!=y||y!=z){
    return 2;
  }
}
```

it fails because the compiler think, that you have not a return statement for the function in every path.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ill-formed:

And if-else statement is as following:

```
if { code }
else { code }
```

So, `if` and `else` blocks make a pair. But you have:

```
if (condition) { code }
code
else { code }
code
```

So, the `code` just above the word `else` breaks this pair, and `else` remains isolated, and thus your program is syntactically incorrect.

You "want" to do:

```
if (x==y || y == z) {
   return 1;
}
else if (x != y || y != z) {
   return 2;
}
```

Moreover, if a `if` (or `else`) block has only one line, you can erase the brackets:

```
if (x==y || y == z)
   return 1;
else if (x != y || y != z)
   return 2;
```

Even more, you algorithms isn't a solution to your problem, ¿how about 3 unique values?. You should check more situations (all diferents, all equals, or only one different).